# KeyUp function is not working when typing fast

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am implementing a javascript search on an HTML page.My code is like this

```js
    $(function () {
        function doSearch(obj, txt) {

         
            var name = $(obj).text();

            if (name != "undefined" && name != null)
            {
                var i = name.toLowerCase().indexOf(txt.toLowerCase());

                if (i >= 0) {
                    var str = name.substr(0, i) + '<b class="selected">' + name.substr(i, txt.length) + '</b>' + name.substr(i + txt.length, name.length)
                    obj.innerHTML = str;
                } else {
                    obj.innerHTML = name;
                }
                return i >= 0;
            }
           
        }
  

        $("#txtesearch").keyup(function () {
            $(".charity-listing").show().find("li").show();
   
            var txt = $("#txtesearch").val().toLowerCase();

            var CharityNames = $(".charity-listing strong").filter(function (idx) {               
                return doSearch(this, txt);
            });
   
            $('.charity-listing li').not(CharityNames.parents("li")).hide();
        
            CharityNames.parents("li").fadeIn();

            var CharityText = $(".charity-listing p").filter(function (idx) {
                return doSearch(this, txt);
            });

            $('.charity-listing li').not(CharityText.parents("li")).hide();

            CharityText.parents("li").fadeIn();

            $(".charity-listing").each(function () {
                if ($(this).find("li").length == $(this).find("li:hidden").length) {
                    $(this).hide();
                } else {
                    $(this).show();
                }
            }); 
   
            $("#txtesearch").each(function () {          
                if ($("#txtesearch").val() == "") {
                    $(".charity-listing").show();
                
                }
            });
            if ($(".charity-listing").find("li:visible").length == 0 && $(".innerbox label.msg").length == 0) {
                $(".pagination-main").append("<label class=\"msg\">There is no search result available to show</label>");    
            }
           
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-left " data-os-animation="fadeInUp" data-os-animation-delay="0s">
                                        
<p class="heading main text-center c5-text">sdf</p>                                                                                      
                                            <input type="text" id="txtesearch">
                                        </div>
<div class="container charity-listing">
            <ul style="list-style:none;">
<li class="col-md-3 odd" style="width:22% !important ;border: 1px solid #ccc;border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;margin:4px 4px 4px 4px">
                       
                   
     <img style="position:inherit !important;right:0px !important;width:100%;max-width:100%;height:auto;" src="/media/1071/17.png">
                    <strong title="Charity test">Charity test</strong>
                    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore</p>

                    

                     <div class="cssCircle plusSign" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tabsec00">
                            +
                     </div>
                    </li>
<li class="col-md-3 even" style="width:22% !important ;border: 1px solid #ccc;border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;margin:4px 4px 4px 4px">
                       
                   
     <img style="position:inherit !important;right:0px !important;width:100%;max-width:100%;height:auto;" src="/media/1071/17.png">
                    <strong title="CharityTesttwo">CharityTesttwo</strong>
                    <p>veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugi</p>

                    

                     <div class="cssCircle plusSign" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tabsec01">
                            +
                     </div>
                    </li>
<li class="col-md-3 odd" style="width:22% !important ;border: 1px solid #ccc;border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;margin:4px 4px 4px 4px">
                       
                   
     <img style="position:inherit !important;right:0px !important;width:100%;max-width:100%;height:auto;" src="/media/1071/17.png">
                    <strong title="Charitynew">Charitynew</strong>
                    <p>s autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p>

                    

                     <div class="cssCircle plusSign" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tabsec02">
                            +
                     </div>
                    </li>
<li class="col-md-3 even" style="width:22% !important ;border: 1px solid #ccc;border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;margin:4px 4px 4px 4px">
                       
                   
     <img style="position:inherit !important;right:0px !important;width:100%;max-width:100%;height:auto;" src="/media/1071/17.png">
                    <strong title="CharitynewTest">CharitynewTest</strong>
                    <p>Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Qu</p>

                    

                     <div class="cssCircle plusSign" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tabsec03">
                            +
                     </div>
                    </li>
             
                </ul>
            

            </div>
```

In ordinary case it works good, But when user types too fast keyUp event is not fired properly. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: try $("#txtesearch").on('keyup', function () {}

Comment: @AniruddhaDas That does the same thing, why would doing that change anything?

Comment: Mind giving an example (*snippet/fiddle*) of this problem? There isn't nearly enough here to see anything wrong.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do in your code block. Try logging every single key which is getting pressed. This way you can evaluate this. change the function to function(e) { console.log(e) }

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Done

Comment: This isn't due to `.keyup()` rather what is happening is that you are trying to filter items that are still hidden from using `.hide()`. For example remove any hides and it will function fine.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I don't completely understand you, Can you please make it a fiddle and post it as an answer here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `keypress` Events instead of `keyup`, you will not get the key up event until the first key is released. This may cause a problem as on fast typing there may be multiple keys which may not be released.

```
$('#txtesearch').keypress(function(e){
  console.log(e.which);
});
```

Comment: It's not working, i have added my entire code now, Please make a check

Comment: *"you will not get the key up event until the first key is released"* actually that's not true, the event handler will still trigger even if an initial key is held down and a new one is pressed and released if that's what you are implying.

Comment: FYI, [the keypress event has been deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event). This applies to [jQuery's keypress as well.](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

Answer (score 0):

The keypress event mentioned in the currently accepted answer has been deprecated. [The spec](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#keypress) recommends using the beforeinput event whenever you need to react before an input to a text field happens, that is, beforeinput is fired after a user presses a key and before the input's value changes.

Just a tiny caveat if you need to support legacy browsers, beforeinput does not work in IE11.

### Example

```js
input = document.querySelector("#beforeinputexample")
input.addEventListener("beforeinput", (e) => {
  // The pressed key (or input data) is passed via the
  // data property of the event argument.
  // Note that data may contain more than one characters,
  // for example when pasting into the textbox.

  if(e.inputType.startsWith("insert")) {
    // This event fires on multiple input types.
    // We're only interested in events that fire
    // when data is entered (the ones that start with
    // "insert".
    
    // Prevent any default browser behaviour, such as
    // filling the text field.
    e.preventDefault()
    
    // Filter the input data before appending to the
    // text box that fired the event.
    e.target.value += e.data.replaceAll(/[0-9]/g, "")
  }  
})
```

```html
<p>This textbox accepts anything <strong>but</strong> the numbers 0-9</p>
<input type="text" id="beforeinputexample">
```